# sort on a list of mp3 tags not working

Tags: c#, mp3

I have the following code that takes a list of tags for mp3 files, then it's supposed to take that list and sort it on the album artist and then by the album names. Only problem is that the sort doesn't work at all. Any help given would be greatly appreciated.

```
List<TagLib.File> pleaseSort = new List<TagLib.File>();
pleaseSort = (List<TagLib.File>)listOfFiles.OrderBy(x => x.Tag.AlbumArtists[0]).ThenBy(x => x.Tag.Album);
```

Comment: `willSort = listOfFiles.OrderBy(x => x.Tag.AlbumArtists[0]).ThenBy(x => x.Tag.Album).ToList();`

Answer (score 1):

You need to invoke ToList() method after sorting the collection, because you can't directly convert from IOrderedEnumerable<> to List<>.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Try instead of creating in the first line the list of files, create list by using `var pleaseSort = ...` adding select statement before using `OrderBy()... select(f => f).OrderBy(...)..`

Comment: when I try to use select it tells me that it does not exist in the current context.

Answer (score 0):

My answer actually came from examining what tags I was wanting to sort by. The Album Artist actually contains null values which causes errors when you are trying to look at element 0 of the array, and after some research I found out that the First Performer field is what I should have been using. After making the switch, the sort works perfectly.